# Manipulate CSV data during upload, is it possible?

Tags: uploads, csv

I am generating membership invoices from client supplied membership list CSV. I created a custom post type, and I'm using wpallimport to upload the CSV data into that custom post type. Each row in the CSV becomes one invoice. This works great.

My challenge is some members on the CSV have more than row of information. There is an "amount" field that needs to be added together. See pic. Amount field needs to be totaled.
[image]

The obvious 1st solution - I asked the client if they would reformat the CSV so this could be done using repeater fields in wpallimport, but their list has about 2500 members so they weren't inclined to edit the csv. They are outputting it from quickbooks.

So my two questions are: Anyone know a way to add up these fields during import? Or would this probably require building an import plugin from scratch or modify an existing one?

Thanks for any suggestions or advice.

Comment: You can write your own functions and run them during import, if you use WP All Import...

Comment: Thanks, I just found out there is a function editor in WP All Import. There may be hope yet!